# Excluding nodata value in band calculation with Rasterio?

Tags: python, nodata, rasterio, band-ratio

How do I exclude no data values when doing a raster calculation with rasterio. I realise that the files are read into an array, and that "0" is a nodata value. However, when I do a simple sum like "image + 1" it applies the math to the nodata value as well. So what is the best way to 'ignore' nodata values in the calculation?

FYI: I am calibrating the Landsat bands to reflectance and this is what my current snippet of the band math looks like:

```
    if "B1.TIF" in band:
        print band
        image = "%s" % (band)
        with rasterio.open(image) as src:
            image_read = src.read(1)
        #np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
        constant = 0.01745329251994444444444444444444 #Constant is calculated (3.14/180) which is converting the sun-angle to sun_radians which was suggested by WOlfgang
        set_mb = "{:.16f}".format(float(mult_band1))
        set_ab = "{:.16f}".format(float(add_band1))
        toa_1 = (float(set_mb) * image_read.astype(float)) + (float(set_ab))
        solar_z = np.cos((90-float(sun_elevation))*float(constant))
        toa_2 = (toa_1.astype(float) / solar_z) * 100000
        kwargs = src.meta
        with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            dst.write_band(1, toa_2.astype(rasterio.uint16))
        #print image_read.mask, toa_2
```

Is there a simple way to ignore nodata values in the calculation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a Numpy masked array that covers up nodata values from Rasterio by adding a keyword argument: `src.read(1, masked=True)`. Operations on a masked array do not use the covered up elements.

If your dataset has no defined nodata value, but you want to use for example `0`, read out a non-masked array and mask it yourself:

```
image_read = src.read(1)
image_read_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(image_read, mask=(image_read == 0))
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It seems like that the band math is still done on the 0 values when adding that keyword argument. 

'src = rasterio.open(image)
   image_read = src.read(1, masked=True)
   image_read.mask
   print image_read'

        '[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]'

Comment: ok so I had a look at the image nodatavals using

`src.nodatavals`

and it returned

`(None,)`

And that is probably why `src.read(1, masked=None)` is not working as a mask.

Any idea as to how to update the bands nodataval to zero?

Comment: Right: if the GeoTIFF has no nodata value set, `masked=True` has no effect. In your case, instead of modifying the Landsat file's nodata value do it all in code: `image_read = src.read(1)` and then `image_read_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(image_read, mask=(image_read == 0))`.

Comment: Another way is with [`numpy.ma.masked_equal(x, value)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_equal.html)

Comment: @sgillies Could I change the nodata value from "None" to "-9999"? ` then image_read = np.ma.masked_values(band, -9999)` would have the desired result.

I need an eloquent way to mask out nodata value which is 'None' from my raster calculations.

Please help

Comment: Mike T: even better!