# Get rid of no-data part of raster in Python

Tags: python, raster, image

I have a raster that, for the most part, contains no-data values. Only on the right side there is data:

[image: what i have]

I would like to get rid of the left part and have a new raster. The extent of the new raster would be the smallest bounding box around the valid data:

[image: what i want]

The part that actually contains the valid data would stay untouched. I am working with Python.

I feel like this is a trivial task but can't think of a reasonable way to do it. I work with the rasterio library but can't find this functionality in their docs.

I don't need the actual code, just an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at

- [`rasterio.windows.get_data_window`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.get_data_window) to get a window of the valid data,
- `rasterio.windows.transform` to calculate a new affine transform,

You would then use [windowed reading](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html) to read only the valid data and then you can write out a new clipped raster.

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.windows import get_data_window, transform, shape

input = 'input.tif'
output = 'output.tif'

with rio.open(input) as src:
    profile = src.profile.copy()
    data_window = get_data_window(src.read(masked=True))
    data_transform = transform(data_window, src.transform)
    profile.update(
        transform=data_transform,
        height=data_window.height,
        width=data_window.width)

    data = src.read(window=data_window)

with rio.open(output, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(data)
```

In the case where your raster doesn't have a nodata value set, find out what value the areas you wish to mask are, then set that as nodata:

```
with rio.open(input, 'r+') as src:  # open as append mode r+
    src.nodata = 0  # my empty areas are 0, so I set them to NoData
    profile = src.profile.copy()
    data_window = get_data_window(src.read(masked=True))
    etc...
```

Input (blue) and output nodata (green) shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and with my data it results in the following error: "AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0" on the get_data_window() line. When I don't specify masked=True then it runs ok but the result is the same size as input. Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone running into the problem I describe in my previous comment, try create the mask yourself instead of having rasterio do it. Have a look at the answer of sgillies in the following question to see how to do it:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224043/excluding-nodata-value-in-band-calculation-with-rasterio

Comment: @JanPisl it's because your raster doesn't have a NoData value set. So the "NoData" areas you refer to aren't considered NoData and your mask is empty. See edit.